# How can I made an AddressBook synchronized with my Iphone addressbook?

Tags: iphone, xcode, synchronization, addressbook

I have to made an app with an AddressBook, different by the internal iphone AddressBook, but I need to take informations from it (and I can do that), and I need to know (if exists) the internal AdressBook last modify date, so i could sync my app's addressbook with the internal one only if it occours, HOW I CAN DO THAT??
THANK YOU AND SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH!

Comment: I am storing contacts, phone numbers and a variable for each phone number, at first time launch I copy the numbers into my app's book, but then i need to keep synchronized the books, is there a last_change_date provided by Apple or something else that permit me the sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing Contacts to your app locally ? 
if Not then You don't have to Sync.

ABAddressBook is centralized DB of contacts. so every time your app open you are using
ABAddressBook to load the contacts it should get the all latest contacts.

Comment: Yes I am storing contacts, phone numbers and a variable for each phone number, at first time launch I copy the numbers into my app's book, but then i need to keep synchronized the books, is there a last_change_date provided by Apple?

Comment: I am not sure..I would use ABAddressBook DB than my own. unless there is no such App requirement.